# Give privilege to new created databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have user "U" who I want to give him full access to all the existing databases except "db1". I want him to only have select privilege for that db. What I did is I gave "U" all permissions for each db one by one and select permission on "db1". What I want to do is to give "U", the create database privilege and full access to any created database by him. Is there anyway that I could do it? I don't want to add privileges every time someone creates a db.

Comment: Same as [this][1] on stackoverflow, some answers there


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases

Comment: could you edit the "this"? its not a link. thanx

Comment: Hmm, it was when i posted it as a answer but it converted to a comment, anyways the link was ment to point to that stackoverflow link at the end

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do this **using permissions only** .

The only way is to create a **stored procedure** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases/2950188#2950188)

If you want to avoid stored procedures, a workaround is:
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON`testuser_%`. * TO 'testuser'@'%';` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950054/let-mysql-users-create-databases-but-allow-access-to-only-their-own-databases/13041542#13041542)); however, this has the problem that the users must then be very careful in naming their databases.

For example if user `aaa` creates database `bbb_xyz`, it can then be accessed exclusively by user `bbb` but not by user `aaa`.